# Is it conceptually right to do a SELECT MAX(id) etc. for finding the last inserted row?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I was reviewing a Drupal module when I found this pattern for getting the id of the row last inserted:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

where the id is a field working in a usual autoincrement way.

Is this conceptually right to do? Is there any situation when this pattern will fail in a MySQL/PostgreSQL environment?

*Edit:*

Thanks for the excellent comments and answers!

I should clarify my question: I meant a situation where someone would like to find out the id of the last inserted row **regardless of the session**.

Comment: Not sure about conceptually right, but I would think if the seed for that column was ever changed it may not be the correct value.

Comment: See [Whats the stardard way of getting the last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048602/whats-the-stardard-way-of-getting-the-last-insert-id)

Comment: Do you mean the last record inserted by the current session?  Or just a generic "what is the newest record in this table"?  Many answers here seem to assume the former, and if that is the case, they are right.  If the process looking a max(id) isn't looking for a record THAT process inserted, I can't think of a scenario where max(id) won't give "the newest record in the table".

Comment: This of course is supposing that `id` is (most likely) an `AUTO INCREMENT IDENTITY NOT NULL` value (which is int based, so it sorts nicely).  If it's anything else (`SEQUENCE`, `CHAR` _generated_ in a similar fashion), this is dangerous.  Still, the only way I'd ever really trust to get the 'most recent row', is to get it based on an `insertTimestamp`.  `SEQUENCE`s can go backwards, `CHAR` sort order may change, and custom ids are ocasionally random (I _think_ it was for a natural key - a card number that would otherwise increment - but I could be wrong).

Comment: @X-Zero - Multiple records can be (and often are) inserted with the same time stamp.  If I wanted a reliable way to get the newest record, regardless of process that created it, I'd use MAX(id) on an identity column.

Comment: @Dems - You're right, they can be.  Of course, depending on use just selecting the top row of a set of duplicate timestamps should be fine.  I guess I'm just too used to some of the craziness around here, where the `MAX()` of nieither the auto-increment id, nor the (mostly) incrementing card number can be used to determine the most-recently enabled card (they added history to the file _after_ the initial import, meaning 'old' cards had newer ids...).

Comment: This is **not** an exact duplicate of the question Ken mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems subjective, but I would say no, it's not conceptually right, because:

- you want the most recently inserted row
- but your query looks at the maximum `id` value

Yes, there is some relationship between max id and most recent insert, but consider the following:

- what if the most recently inserted row was deleted?

Answer on MySQL:  you get different results.  Note that there doesn't even have to be multithreading or multiple processes for this to fail.  That's because they're two different things *(which admittedly can often produce the same results).*

```
select max(id) from <tablename>
```

vs

```
select last_insert_id()
```

(Guess which one is right.)

---

@Dems pointed out that the OP is ambiguous.  I'll clarify my main point:

**We're talking about three different pieces of information:**

- maximum `id` value
- `id` of row most recently inserted, specific to a session
- `id` of row most recently inserted into table (regardless of session)

The dangerous thing is that sometimes, querying for one will give the right answer for another -- **but not always**.

Comment: It matters whether the OP means to find the last inserted record "by this session", or just the newest record in the table.  It's a fundamentally different question, and I have no idea which the OP is asking.

Answer (score 5):

select max(id) would only be guaranteed to retrieve the record with the highest ID. it may not necessarily be the LAST record inserted into the table. Remember that DB operations can be run in parallel. You might insert a record and get ID #5. But by the time you get around to doing the `select MAX(id)`, someone else might have inserted another record and now the max is really #6 instead.

As well, you can't use it to predict what the next assigned ID might be. Consider the case where some inserts are done in a transaction. The last committed record in the DB is #5 again, then 3 inserts are performed (#6, #7, #8), and then they're rolled back. The next insert to be performed will actually be #9, not #6 again - mysql does not recycle ID numbers from failed transactions. And there's no guarantee that YOU would get #9 either - some other session could do the insert before you get around to it, so your fourth insert might be #10, or #10,000,000 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, in [MySQL there's a far nicer way of getting this information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: That's assuming you're talking about an insert you just did.  What if it was in a different session?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can simply use last_insert_id () which is more guaranteed to work.

Comment: `last_insert_id ()` work only in current session supposed that YOU have add auto-increment value, another client will not see yours new value by last_insert_id ()

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the WHERE clause and how the application inserts into that table. `SELECT max(ID) FROM table` will always return the biggest ID at the time the query runs. Assuming ID is a primary key auto_increment, then it will return the most recent row. However, in multi-threaded environments like web servers, that may not be the ID you are expecting since another process may have inserted into that table as well. For example, if your PHP code inserts into the table, then does `select max(id)` expecting to get that row it just inserted, it may not work because another process may have inserted another row after you did your insert and before you did your `select max`.

If the ID is a primary key auto_increment (mysql) then MySql's `last_insert_id()` or PHP's [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is usually a better choice. But again, without knowing the table, the WHERE clause, or what Drupal is expecting from this query, it isn't possible to say if Drupal is "doing it wrong."

Answer (score 1):

Read this one: [Directive 595](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Directive-595.aspx)

Epic fail to trust MAX(id), it fails big time.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL you have to deal with `sequences` so all depends how its configured

Comment: DB2 has `sequences` too, which can count backwards!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your particular situation, I would say that this is not a safe way. Think of a situation where you have multiple clients inserting records all the time.  You can get yourself into a race condition with very nasty consequences.  You can try some creating locking, but that may end up introducing a bad bottleneck.

Comment: It does depend on what this is being used for.  But I couldn't work out a race condition that *matters*.  Process A starts inserting 100 records, process B starts inserting 1 record, process B is blocked by A, it's record will always have a higher id.  I actually can't create a scenario in my head that could lead to an earlier record appearing after a later record when ordered by an identity column.