# Hibernate asscociate single entry in Orders with multiple entries in OrdersDetails by column order_id

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys

**Orders**

[image]

**OrderDetails**

[image]

I'm new to Hibernate.
In JDBC I used to get new order_id using

```
select ifnull(max(order_id)+1,1) from Orders;
```

I get this new order_id in Hibernate using coalesce() instead of ifnull.

- I used to set this new order_id to textbox in Order Form.
- As you add elements in shopping cart, similarly I used to add order_id, product_id and quantity in table **OrderDetails**.
- When I click on save button, order_id, customer_id and current date will be stored in table **Orders**.

How can I achieve this in Hibernate using primary and foreign key?

Comment: You should use hibernate [generated identifier values](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators) for this purpose.

Comment: where an I get example?

Comment: @SternK auto_increment is not my problem. My problem is about mapping

Comment: What database do you use? What do you use `auto_increment` or `sequence`? And look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345399/is-it-conceptually-right-to-do-a-select-maxid-etc-for-finding-the-last-insert). I guess `select ifnull(max(order_id)+1,1) from Orders` is a wrong way for obtaining a new entity identifier.

Comment: I used mysql.
Because of Error I've changed it to ifnull(max(order_id),1) and added 1 latter while setting value to textbox