# Retrieve the latest value from an Auto-Incremented id-field?

Tags: sql-server-2000, c#-2.0

[I am from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Suppose I have a Table:

```
FieldWorker{ ID, Name, WorkingArea}
```

And, `ID` is an auto-incremented field.

Now, suppose, I am using the following code to insert records:

```
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO [FieldWorker]
       ([Name]
       ,[WorkingArea])
 VALUES
       (@Name
       ,@WorkingArea)");
```

What technique can I use to retrieve the maximum value of auto-incremented `ID` field that has been generated upon the insertion of the latest record?

Both the insertion-code and the retrieval of `ID`-value  must be done under a single `SqlTransaction` object.

Why must I use `ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2000, you'd need to do this with [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28SQL.80%29.aspx) and ExecuteScalar

```
sqlComm.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO [FieldWorker]
       ([ID]
       ,[Name]
       ,[WorkingArea])
 VALUES
       (@ID
       ,@Name
       ,@WorkingArea);
       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
```

For SQL Server 2005+, you use the OUTPUT clause

```
sqlComm.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO [FieldWorker]
       ([ID]
       ,[Name]
       ,[WorkingArea])
 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
 VALUES
       (@ID
       ,@Name
       ,@WorkingArea);");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set ID as Identity (auto increment)
2) You can get the last Identity number inserted as follow

```
@@IDENTITY
```

Reference [SQL Identity Number](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Not safe. Your link even states that. -1 for ignoring your own link

Answer (score 0):

If the ID field is autoincremented you don't need to include in your insert.

Further you can use Scope_Identity().

For more information you can visit this blog

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/