# How to get last id if any column in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

I am trying to get the last id (Last value of an `identity` column) to show it on control incremented by 1 each time when data is inserted to table.

How to get this last id in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 using C#?

Comment: Do you mean "just after an insert" (if so, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`), or do you mean "at any point"? Note: there's not much benefit in the second case, as you can't guarantee that you'll get +1 next time (other spids etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity columns are incremented in the database, not on the C# side.  You can query for the last value like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
```

Comment: That just gives you the max value currently in the table - but the `IDENTITY` column could be on a higher value, if the last several inserts were all rolled back by transaction. This is **NOT** at all a reliable way to check

Comment: @marc_s - That's true.  +1 to your answer.

Comment: Thank you Jirka Han.You did really well but i am looking for is what i m going to post. after 1 day of tricky practice i found a absolut solution for my question.Pleas have a look here.

Answer (score 2):

Either just grab the latest ID when the insert happens (using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`), or if you need to check the current value of an `IDENTITY` column later on, use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')` to get that value.

So the easiest way is to just get the ID as you insert your values - something like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, ..., ColN) VALUES(@Val1, ..., @ValN); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    _ID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Or if you cannot grab the ID as it's being inserted, you can always check later on what the current last used value of the `IDENTITY` column on a given table was, using something like this:

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('{0}');", yourTableName);

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    _ID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
```

or this

```
SELECT MAX(SomeID) FROM SomeTable;
```

**EDIT**

Best way to use

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY]
```

and in C# you could call

```
Int32 _ID = 0;
//you could use second variant sql= "SELECT MAX(SomeID) FROM SomeTable";
string sql =
    "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        _ID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Nice link to feel difference 
[Using @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY with triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_s Oh i see, thank you. by the way i found interesting link where showed some example why We shouldn't use @@Identity http://cgaskell.wordpress.com/2006/11/15/using-identity-vs-scope_identity-and-further-implications-with-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM table_name ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

or in LINQ:

```
context.table.Select(x->x.Id).OrderByDescending(x->x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `.Max(x => x.Id)` seems a lot more direct... Maybe `.Max(x => (int?)x.Id)` if concerned about zero rows.

Comment: That just gives you the max value currently in the table - but the `IDENTITY` column could be on a higher value, if the last several inserts were all rolled back by transaction. This is **NOT** at all a reliable way to check