# Insert and select in one statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

I have a table `Absences`

```
|  Id  |  Name  |  Job  |
-------------------------
|  1   |  James |   1   |
-------------------------
|  2   |  Simon |   1   |
-------------------------
```

Where ID is  an identity `Primary Key` incrementing by 1.
I'm accessing this table from a program in C# and I need to do the following :

`Insert Into Absences (Name, Job) Values ('aName', 'aJob')`

The problem is I need to get the `Id` column where i'm inserting at the same time because `Name`and `Job` are not unique so I won't be able to retreive this exact column after.

Is it possible to add a select on the `Id` column in that query ?

---

Update

```
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"SomeConnection");
  myConnection.Open();
  SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
  myCommand.CommandText = "Insert Into Absences (Name, Job) Values ('aName', 'aJob')";
  int currentAbs = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

I get an error on the ExecuteScalar Line. Object reference is not set to and instance of object.

Comment: [Scope identity sometimes returns incorrect value](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).  Use an `OUTPUT` clause as suggested in workarounds.

Comment: @HABO - Is this bug also confirmed in SQL 2008?

Comment: @PhilMurray - AFAIK, it was fixed during the lifetime of 2008, but I haven't found a statement as to precisely when.  It is marked as "Closed as fixed."

Comment: I changed the type cast to `Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());` and it worked... any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will give you the value of the identity column of the newly inserted row from within the same scope.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"SomeConnection");
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "Insert Into Absences (Name, Job) Values ('aName', 'aJob'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
int currentAbs = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

[Scope Identity Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: So this gives me the Highest current Identity ?

Comment: No, because the highest identity is not necessarily the inserted row.

Comment: Gives me another exception on the same line. Specified cast is not valid..

Comment: Can you check that the insert succeeded?

Comment: @PhilMurray yes the insert works

Comment: And if you run that SQL query straight on your database?  What does it return?

Comment: It returns the correct identity column...

Comment: Ooooh I changed the type cast to `Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());` and it worked... any idea why ?

Comment: Weird.  What was the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SqlCommand`, then you can use

```
int lastId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

to retrieve the unique id of the inserted record.
Take a look at [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Niice this sound pretty much like what I need although how can I access this from my C# program ?

Comment: Mmm i get Object reference is not set to an instance of object.. I'll post my code above If you can take a quick look maybe i'm not using it right

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: which line gives you this error?

Comment: The executeScalar(). I added and update to my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

After this query you can select **@@identity** to get the last inserted id in mssql server.

Comment: Be careful with Identity and scoping. SCOPE_IDENTITY() is safer

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` immediately after you insert your record:

```
int id;
string query = "Insert Into Absences (Name, Job) Values ('aName', 'aJob')";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
    connection.Open();
    // execute your INSERT query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // get the last-inserted ID
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
    id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```