# insert into two tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

1. RESERVATION

   `ID`, `DATE`, `TIME`, `TABLE`
2. CLIENT

   `ID_CLIENT`, `FNAME`, `LNAME`, `EMAIL`, `PHONE`, `FK_RESERVATION`

I have working `INSERT` statement for Reservation Table-

```
 string insertSql = "INSERT INTO Rezervacija (date,time,table) VALUES (@date,@time,@table);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, con);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txtDate.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", ddlTime.SelectedItem.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", ddlTable.SelectedItem.Text);
```

But the problem comes with `INSERT INTO Client Table Foreign Key`.

Can anyone help me how to insert data into two related tables.

Comment: Which database system are you using? Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is to do with the foreign key constraint from `Client` to `Reservation`. Do you know what foreign keys are and how they work?

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify your query to get the ID of the row that you just inserted.

```
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO Rezervacija (date,time,table) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id VALUES (@date,@time,@table);"
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, con);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txtDate.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", ddlTime.SelectedItem.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", ddlTable.SelectedItem.Text);

var **reservationId** = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()

string insertSql2 = "INSERT INTO CLIENT (ID_CLIENT,FNAME,LNAME,EMAIL,PHONE,FK_RESERVATION) VALUES (@clientId, @fname, @lname, @email, @phone, @reservation"

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertSql2, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientId", clientId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation", **reservationId**);
```

This will allow you use the Inserted.Id in your second query as you've returned the output to a variable.

Comment: I forgot to add, TABLE is a keyword in SQL, so you'll have to change it to [table].