# SQL - Insert multiple records from select

Tags: sql-server, database, multiple-insert

I have been searching all day but could not find answer to this:

I have a table on SQL Server:

dbo.Program

with fields:

- Program.id...PK autoincrement
- Program.user...varchar
- Program.program...varchar
- Program.installed...boolean
- Program.department...varchar
- Program.wheninstalled...date

Now, **I want to insert a new record for every distinct user and copy the department from his latest(Program.wheninstalled) record with other values the same for every user:**

- Program.user...*every unique user*
- Program.program...MyMostAwesomeProgram
- Program.installed...false
- Program.department...*department of the record with the latest program.wheninstalled field* of all the records of the unique user in program.user
- Program.wheninstalled...null

I know how to do it in an ugly way:

1. select the latest records for every user and their department in that record
2. extract values from 1) and make it into insert into
   (field1, field2...fieldX) values
   (1records_value1, 1records_value2...1records_valueX),
   (2records_value1, 2records_value2...2records_valueX),
   ...
   (Nrecords_value1, Nrecords_value2...Nrecords_valueX)

but I would like to know how to do it in a better way. Oh I cannot use some proper HR databse to make my life easier so this is what I got to work with now.

Answer (score 1):

you said you know how to do the select

```
insert into Program (user, program, installed, department, wheninstalled)
select user, 'MyMostAwesomeProgram', 'false' , department, null 
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a postgres guy, but something akin to the below should work:

```
insert into Program (user, program, installed, department, wheninstalled)
select user, 
   'MyMostAwesomeProgram', 
   false, 
   (select department from someTable where u.user = ...),
   null
from users as u;
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23905173/3430807

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
insert into Program (user, program, installed, department, whenInstalled)
select user, program, installed, department, whenInstalled
from 
(
    select User
    , 'MyMostAwesomeProgram' program
    , 0 installed
    , department
    , null whenInstalled
    , row_number() over (partition by user order by whenInstalled desc, id desc) r
from Program
) p
where p.r = 1
```

The interesting bit is the `row_number() over (partition by user order by whenInstalled desc, id desc) r`.

This says to return a column, `r`, which holds values 1..n for each `user`, counting up according to the order by clause (i.e. starting with the most recent `whenInstalled` and working backwards).

I also included the `id` field in the order by clause in case there were two installs for the same user on the same date; in such a case the most recently added (the one with the higher `id` is used first).

We then put this in a subquery, and select only the first record; thus we have 1 record per user, and it's the most recent.

The only values we use from this record are the `user` and `department` fields; all else is defined per your defaults.

Comment: ps. good blog on this & similar functions here if you'd like to read up on it.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your query helped me a lot to get it done finally. Now I understand partition vs vs group by, those short aliases and at the end I used some rank function becouse your query resulted on only one row returned. But with rank it works perfectly :]. Anyway for those who might google this:

Answer (score 0):

So I am gonna answer this for some other people who might google this:

1. To get a records from a table to another table you need to use *Select into* statement
2. I like using *With* XXX as ( some select) to specify, say, "virtual" table with which you can work during the query
3. As JohnLBevan meantioned a very useful function *Row_number*, *over*, *partition by* and what i missed is a *rank*

So once you read on these you should be able to understand how to do what I wanted to do.