# Something goes wrong dealing with images

Tags: asp.net

I am really confused .I have table with 3 columns called id,title,images .What I want to do is to store images in the db.But I couldnt .I am getting exception  at this line

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Connnection state seems open.What else do i need to check?

```
 SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            Byte[] imgByte = null;
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
            {
                HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
            }
            connection = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Northwind;UID=sa;Password=1234");

            connection.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO imgtable (title,images) VALUES(@theTitle, @theImage) SELECT @@IDENTITY";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theTitle", txtTitle.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theImage", imgByte);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: When you say "something goes wrong" what do you mean? What exception message do you see?

Comment: By the way: `INSERT` does *not* return an ID! And you `INSERT ... SELECT` is not valid SQL syntax.

Comment: the elves went on strike

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id) would help.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball is telling me that you get an error about invalid SQL syntax. That is because you can not execute two statements by just writing them on one line.

**Put a semicolon** between the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO imgtable (title,images) VALUES(@theTitle, @theImage); SELECT @@IDENTITY";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MSDN documentation [SQLCommand ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they give a complete example:

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
    Int32 newProdID = 0;
    string sql =
        "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return (int)newProdID;
}
```

Juste replace `int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` by `int id = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`.

Also edit your SQL statement like this: "INSERT INTO imgtable (title,images) VALUES(@theTitle, @theImage); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";

Comment: That's not the source of the problem. `Convert.ToInt32` and `(Int32)` are equivalent if the result of `ExecuteScalar` is actually an `int`. The problem is that `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` throws an error due to invalid SQL.