# Get last id from SQL Server DB in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need to make a function that return the last inserted id, and the connection isn't working

Code:

```
Private Function lastId() As Integer
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("data source=localhost;User Id=root;database=farmacia")
        Dim query = "SELECT max(id_client) FROM clients"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Please do a little research. There is a function like this (indeed there are 3) in SQL-SERVER

Comment: What "isn't working" about it? What error do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: It says that it cant find the server

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me - your code isn't able to find the server with the provided connection string.  Double check your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your connection string you cannot connect to the database as specified so you should change the connection string :

you should specify `AttachDbFilename`,`Initial Catalog` for a proper connection

**for example:**

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + constring + ";Initial        Catalog=mydatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

**SQL Server Connection String Tags**

- **Initial Catalog**= Since there is only one database per file in VistaDB, there is no concept of an initial catalog.
- **User Id**= All database files are fully available to VistaDB connections, there are no per user restrictions.
- **Trusted_Connection**= All connections are trusted.
- **Integrated Security**= No concept since all users have to be logged into a machine in order to reach the file.
- **Network Library**= There is only one managed assembly for VistaDB, libraries are not used.
- **MultipleActiveResultSets**= MARS is not supported at this time.
- **AttachDbFilename**= The filename is part of the DataSource identifier.
- **Failover Partnering**= There are no server components or mirroring in VistaDB. 
  Asynchronous Processing= All connections are synchronous in VistaDB. Asynchronous operation is not supported.

**For more details** : http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/vistadb/learn-more/tutorials/connection-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is the connection string that you need to connect to the server.
you need to write your SQL password in the connection string.

```
Private Function lastId() As Integer
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=myPassword;database=farmacia")
        Dim query = "SELECT max(id_client) FROM clients"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
End Function
```

This query is okay for finding the latest inserted id

```
SELECT max(id_client) FROM clients
```

You were getting  that error coz of the Connection string