# Return id after insert C# using SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, return-value, scope-identity

I know this question has been on this site many times, but I can't get my code working.

I have an `Insert` statement, and I need the id from that statement on my asp.net page.

I'm getting the `return value 0`.

```
public int newid { get; set; }

public void CreateAlbum(string _titel, string _name, string _thumb, int _userid)
{
    objCMD = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO tblFotoalbum 
                                  (fldAlbumHead, fldAlbumName, fldAlbumThumb, fldUserID_FK)
                              VALUES 
                                  (@titel, @name, @thumb, @userid);

                              SET @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titel", _titel);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", _name);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thumb", _thumb);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", _userid);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newid", newid);

    objData.ModifyData(objCMD);       
}
```

Comment: Did you expect the property newid to be set with the value of SCOPE_IDENTITY? This is not the way in which parameters work.

Comment: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: What is `objData` and what does `.ModifyData()` on that object do??

Comment: Steve - yeah that was my idea, but i'm not hardcore to sql yet :)

Comment: marc_s - objData is a instance of my DataAccess file, modifyData is:

 public void ModifyData(SqlCommand CMD)
        {
            CMD.Connection = strCon;
            strCon.Open();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            strCon.Close();
        }

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int CreateAlbum(string _titel, string _name, string _thumb, int _userid)
{
    // define return value - newly inserted ID
    int returnValue = -1;

    // define query to be executed
    string query = @"INSERT INTO tblFotoalbum (fldAlbumHead, fldAlbumName, fldAlbumThumb, fldUserID_FK)
                              VALUES (@titel, @name, @thumb, @userid);
                     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"

    // set up SqlCommand in a using block   
    using (objCMD = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) 
    {
        // add parameters using regular ".Add()" method 
        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@titel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = _titel;
        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = _name;
        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@thumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = _thumb;
        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = _userid;

        // open connection, execute query, close connection
        connection.Open();
        object returnObj = objCMD.ExecuteScalar();

        if(returnObj != null)
        {
           int.TryParse(returnObj.ToString(), out returnValue);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    // return newly inserted ID
    return returnValue;
}
```

Not sure how you can integrate that with your `objData` class - maybe you need to add a new method to that DAL class for this.

Check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Okay, i will try this, and how do i access the return value on my asp codebehinde?

Comment: @HenrikS: the new `ID` value is returned from the `CreateAlbum` method as an `int` ....

Answer (score 3):

Given the sql statement you are using, you need to configure `@newid` as an output parameter:

```
var newIdParam = objCMD.Parameters.Add("@newid", SqlDbType.Int32)
newIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.OutPut;
```

then you execute the command using ExecuteNonQuery, and after that you can read the ouptut parameter:

```
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int newId = Convert.ToInt32(newIdParam.Value);
```

EDIT:
I guess ModifyData method set the connection property and calls ExecuteNonQuery, so your code would be:

```
objData.ModifyData(objCMD);      
int newId = Convert.ToInt32(newIdParam.Value);
```

Comment: i'm getting an error: 

ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Comment: Obviously you need to set the connection property of objCmd and make sure it is open before Executing it: objCmd.Connection = YouConnection;

Comment: Now i just get the value 0

Comment: Are you sure tblFotoalbum table has an identity column?

Comment: I like this answer because it works with parameters

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case as this works for SQL SERVER 2000

- for 2005+ use

  `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID`

Like

```
INSERT INTO Roles(UserId)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES(@UserId)
```

Comment: Isnt this just for triggers?

Comment: Perhaps you mean for the OP to use the OUTPUT clause?

Comment: any chance you've copied this from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5228819/57475. If so, link to that answer and say where you've taken/adapted the code from. regardless of that fact, this still doesn't really answer the question in any direct manner.

Comment: The OUTPUT clauses requires an INTO with a temporary (in memory) table! You should complete your otherwise valid example.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using CommandText you shouldn't forget adding **"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"** end of CommandText line.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: I spent 2 hours to learn this answer. maybe you understood wrongly me according to my bad english.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. My point was solely about the shape of the information, not the content. When you answer the question, you might want to give a more detailed explanation so that a person asking the question and others can benefit. In this particular case, I would expect to see some more details about why one should not forget adding `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Hope you get my point.

Comment: yes thanks. this was my first comment this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an output variable to do it. You could just use a `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last id inserted on database and use the `ExecuteScalar()` method from `DbCommand`.

```
public int newid { get; set; }

public void CreateAlbum(string _titel, string _name, string _thumb, int _userid)
{
    objCMD = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO tblFotoalbum 
                           (fldAlbumHead, fldAlbumName, fldAlbumThumb, fldUserID_FK)
                           VALUES 
                           (@titel, @name, @thumb, @userid);

                           SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titel", _titel);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", _name);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thumb", _thumb);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", _userid);
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newid", newid);

    objData.ModifyData(objCMD);     


    newid = (int)objCMD.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I don't know `objData` object does, but take a look how you execute your command.

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT` instead of SET? Anyway, using the `OUTPUT inserted.ID` clause is preferable. You use only a single insert statement and  don't have to worry about inserting in multiple tables with identity keys in the same batch.

Comment: We don't know what ModifyData does, but probably this is the best way to have a duplicate record in the db.

Comment: @FelipeOriani this cannot end well. The ExecuteScalar runs everything not only the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY. If ModifyData inserts a  record, calling again ExecuteScalar inserts another copy of the same data

Comment: Yes Steve, the OP should provide for us what the `ModifyData` does.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution (and AFAIK also the only really safe one) is to use the `OUTPUT` clause as in this example:

```
DECLARE @newIdTable(newid INT);
INSERT INTO table(...) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @newIdTable VALUES (...);
SELECT TOP 1 newid FROM @newIdTable;
```

I suggest you put this into a stored procedure and call it using `ExecuteScalar`, which would return the value of the last select.

Answer (score 0):

check with SCOPE_IDENTITY()..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190315.asp