# How to know the identity value to use in another stored procedure, Inserting from a windows form

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I need to use the Identity value of a an inserted record, to insert in another table. The insertions are done using stored procedures, which are called from a winforms button event. Procedures are parameterised, so i can't execute the first procedure in another procedure

```
Procedure [dbo].[insert_trans] (
  @name nvarchar(50),
  @email nvarchar(50),
  @ata_certification bit,
  @St1 nvarchar(50),
  @St2 nvarchar(50),
  @City nvarchar(MAX),
  @State nvarchar(MAX),
  @Country nvarchar(MAX),
  @Zipcode numeric(18, 0),
  @Qualification nvarchar(50),
  @Interpreting_service bit ,
  @Tran_Int_Degree bit,
  @Total_Experience int,
  @Native_language nvarchar(50),
  @Resume bit
) as
begin
    insert into Location_Master (
        St1,
        St2, 
        City, 
        State, 
        Country, 
        Zipcode
    ) values (
        @St1,
        @St2,
        @City,
        @State,
        @Country,
        @Zipcode)

    Declare @Location_id int
    set @Location_id = (SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS varchar(10))
                        AS LAST_IDENTITY)

    insert into Translators values (
        @name, 
        @email,
        @ata_certification,
        @Location_id,             
        @Qualification, 
        @Interpreting_service,
        @Tran_Int_Degree,             
        @Total_Experience, 
        @Native_language, 
        @Resume)

end
```

and the second procedure, where I require the sno generated

```
procedure insert_langknown (
    @translator_id int,
    @Language_code varchar(50)
) as
begin

    Insert into Language_known (
        translator_id,
        Language_code
    ) values (
        @translator_id,
        @Language_code)
end
```

The translator id is the required field

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Make the first procedure return the value of the newly inserted identity column.  You can retrieve the new identity value with [`scope_identity`()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: Do you need the procedures or the form code?

Comment: Preferably both. I want to see what classes you are using to call the procs and what the procs do.

Comment: @Andomar How do i use  scope_identity() returned value in another procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id Note that scope_identity() is no longer required for newer version of SQL.

Comment: @Michael: What's the alternative?

Comment: @Andomar `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` or whatever the name of the Identity column happens to be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the recent inserted key via following way

```
 EXEC [Schema].[YourSpName] @Parameter ='ParamValue'
 SELECT  @@Identity
```

Scope_Identity() will return you NULL because connection scope will be lost.

Alternatively, you can use IDENT_CURRENT to be sure about the actual result as it is not dependent upon connection or scope.

```
  EXEC [Schema].[YourSpName] @Parameter ='ParamValue'
  SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('YourTableName')
```

**Edit 1**
As mentioned by Andomar, I will suggest you to return Scope_Identity from your stored procedure or use transaction to ensure that you are locking rows.

**Edit 2**
You can modify your SP to return OUTPUT value which you can use while calling other SP, like below

**Stored procedure**

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE insertSomething
(
 @Name varchar(20),
 @EffectIveRows INT OUTPUT
)
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES (@Name)
SELECT @EffectIveRows = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

**Second SP**

```
procedure insert_langknown
              (
                   @translator_id int,
                   @Language_code varchar(50)
                   @LastIdentityValue INT,

               )
               as
            begin
               -- USE @LastIdentityValue variable 
            Insert into Language_known (translator_id,Language_code) values ( @translator_id,@Language_code)
```

**Calling your SP**

```
DECLARE @Output INT = 0
EXEC insertSomething 'A' , @EffectIveRows = @Output OUTPUT

EXEC insert_langknown @translator_id= 2, @Language_code= 'dummy Data'  ,@LastIdentityValue = @Output
```

Comment: -1 This is not concurrent. If another connection inserts another row before you call `@@identity` or `ident_current()`, you'll get the wrong value.

Comment: @Andomar Agree, I did forget that. I have edited my answer with suggestion.

Comment: Can u modify the second procedure i posted?

Comment: @newuser I have modified my answer with modified SP

Comment: i modified my sp1, and added the folllowing code to my form: SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@EffectIveRows", SqlDbType.Int);
                retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                Command.Parameters.Add(retval);                                      but it gives the following error                                                                                         Procedure or function 'insert_trans' expects parameter '@EffectIveRows', which was not supplied.

Comment: You have to provide a default value to it. Just like in my example I have given 0 to it. I have very less c# knowledge but I remember that you can provide value to SqlParameter also

Answer (score 0):

You can return value from store procedure as below

```
Select Scope_Identity()
```

and can access the return value in vb.net code as below

```
command.ExecuteScalar()
```

otherwise you directly send the inserted value record to another procedure simply as

```
DECLARE @RETURNVAL INT
SELECT @RETURNVAL=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

EXEC ANOTHER_PROCEDURE @RETURNVAL,another_parameter


-- 'ANOTHER_PROCEDURE' is Storepd procedure name
```