# While Inserting data into two tables =>ERROR: "Invalid column name Id"

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting this error

> Invalid column name Id.

What is wrong?

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            connection.Open();              
            try
            {
                string query2 = "INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupName) OUTPUT 
                                 Inserted.Id VALUES (@SupName)";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupName", txtCname.Text);

                int supID = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                //cmd2.Parameters.Clear();

                string query3 = "INSERT INTO SupplierContacts (SupConAddress, 
                                 SupConCity, AffiliationId, SupplierId) 
                                 VALUES (@SupConAddress, @SupConCity, 
                                 @AffiliationId, @SupplierId)";
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, connection);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupConAddress", txtCaddress.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupConCity", txtCcity.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AffiliationId", aff.AffilitationId);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierId", supID);
                // cmd3.Parameters.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            connection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Presumably `Suppliers` doesn't have a column called `ID`.

Comment: yes it does, SupplierId

Comment: Perhaps you're running an old SQL Server version that doesn't understand `Inserted.Id` - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)?

Comment: Am i writing the syntax wrong?

Comment: `SupplierId` is not the same as `Supplier.Id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are right, so where do you see Supplier.Id here? Sorry i am slightly confused..

Comment: @neha . . . `Inserted.Id` refers to `Suppliers.Id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But that's the syntax .. right? I am totally new in sql and didn't know much. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `OUTPUT` clause.  However, the correct syntax requires a table name.  In T-SQL, this might be written as:

```
DECLARE @SupplierIds TABLE (SupplierId int);

INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupName)
    OUTPUT Inserted.SupplierId INTO @SupplierIds
    VALUES (@SupName);
```

This is saying to put the new value of `SupplierId` into the table `SupplierIds`.  You can then retrieve the value by referring to the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM @SupplierIds;
```

However, you cannot reference the table across multiple queries.

My suggestion is that you run the whole script using multiple statements.  Or (what I would probably do) write a stored procedure with all the logic for inserting into both tables.

Comment: Okies, I will give it a try.. Thanks!!