# Insert two data in different row with same id in another data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem in inserting two data in different row with same id in another data;

in my DAL:

```
public DataTable test(string name, string course)
    {
        string insertsql = "INSERT INTO Table1(schName) OUTPUT INSERTED.addID  values (@schName)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertsql,conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schName", name);
        conn.Open();


        var table1Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        string insertsql1 = "INSERT INTO Table2(ScholarshipID,DiplomaCourse) values (@id,@course)";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertsql1, conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", table1Id);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;

    }
```

in my codebehind(cs)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  addScholarship[] test = new addScholarship[1];

        string course = "";
        string name = schName.Text;
        scholarshipBLL obj = new scholarshipBLL();

        List<addScholarship> addScholarshipList = new List<addScholarship>();

        addScholarship scholarship;


        if (DIT.Checked )
        {
            scholarship = new addScholarship(name, course);
            addScholarshipList.Add(scholarship);
            course = "DIT";
            DataTable dt = obj.test(name, course);

        }

        if (DFI.Checked)
        {
            scholarship = new addScholarship(name, course);
            addScholarshipList.Add(scholarship);
            course = "DFI";
            DataTable dt = obj.test(name, course);
        }


    }
```

so there will be two checkboxes. right now it currently works if the user clicks on one checkbox. when the user clicks both checkboxes, it will give error such as:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

now i have closed it. once i click submit, it will insert twice.

table1

id  schName

1   hi

2   hi

table 2

tableId       id     course

1              1      dfi

2              2     dit

where it should be like

table1

id     schName

1        hi

table2

tableId    Id    course

1           1     dfi

2           1     dit

Comment: put code conn.Close();

Comment: where shld i close it

Comment: It is clear from the error that you are not closing the connection. You should close the connection before you return from test method.

Comment: i have closed it. i still getting two same data inserted twice @chetanranpariya

Comment: Please go thru the answer I posted below. It was again a logic only which you were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again your are not thinking logically. It is obvious that you are adding rows into both table1 and table2 in test method. So if you call this method two times it will add rows in to both tables two times.

If you want to add only row in table1 then you should create a separate method for that and call it only once. And you should create another method to add rows in table2 and you should call it from the if block.

Following are the tow methods you need to have in scholarshipBLL class.

```
public int AddSholarship(string scholarshipName)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(....))
    {
        string insertsql = "INSERT INTO Table1(schName) OUTPUT INSERTED.addID  values (@schName)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertsql,conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schName", name);
        var table1Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return table1Id;
    }
}

public DataTable AddCourse(string scholarshipId, string courseName)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(....))
    {
        string insertsql1 = "INSERT INTO Table2(ScholarshipID,DiplomaCourse) values (@id,@course)";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertsql1, conn);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", scholarshipId);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", courseName);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

And button_Click Code should be changed as following.

```
string course = "";
string scholarshipName = schName.Text;
scholarshipBLL obj = new scholarshipBLL();

List<addScholarship> scholarshipList = new List<addScholarship>();

var scholarshipId = obj.AddSholarship(scholarshipName);

addScholarship scholarship;
if (DIT.Checked )
{
    scholarship = new addScholarship(Name,course);
    scholarshipList.Add(scholarship);
    course = "DIT";
    DataTable dt = obj.AddCourse(scholarshipId, course);
}

if (DFI.Checked)
{
    scholarship = new addScholarship(Name,course);
    scholarshipList.Add(scholarship);
    course = "DFI";
    DataTable dt = obj.AddCourse(scholarshipId, course);
}
```

Comment: just curious, but why run 2 separate queries when you can insert both rows in the same query using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and a transaction to return the newly inserted id? less database calls, less code

Comment: It's not about how many queries. It's about when to run which query. In this particular case only one row should be inserted in the Table1 and Two Rows to be inserted in Table2. If both the insert operations are happening in single method and that method is called two times then it will insert two rows in both the tables. So the logical solution is to insert one row in Table1 and store the newId in a variable and use it for inserting rows in Table2. That is why I create two different methods One for inserting in "Table1" and other for inserting in "Table2".

Comment: the same can still be achieved using a single query inside a transaction. With this method depending on the number of courses being added to the scolarship you will end up with multiple database calls.

Comment: Agreed, what you are suggesting can also be done. Its just the matter of implementation. This problem can be solved in various ways. The solution I suggested was in line with the author's current implementation. By looking at the author's level of expertise on ADO.NET, SQL and C# I did not prefer to make it complex and difficult for the author to understand.

Comment: Perhaps its just me being overly concerned with performance (the system im designing needs to be incredibly streamlined) so im very conscious on resources being used

Comment: it has successfully inserted like what i want. but in table2 it appeared DIT and space for DFI @ChetanRanpariya which means DFI is not inserted properly?

Comment: it is useful as it helps my error but i keep getting new thing error. right now, either one will be inserted like 'DFI','  ' or 'DIT','   ' @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and understand what could be reason behind it? What changes you have made to your code? Did you implement the solution I suggested in the answer? Please try to debug and find the problem area before posting problems?

Comment: @Takarii What you are saying very true. Resource consumption is surely an area which should be address while designing and coding too. And it requires experience, technology knowledge and thinking process to have that level of maturity. A well thought solution is always possible for any problem but sometimes the solution has to be at the level of the understanding of the person who asks the question.

Comment: what i have done is that instead of creating that two method in BLL, i have created it in my DAL. afterwhich i will call those method in BLL and call them in the presenter view. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: scholarship = new addScholarship(Name,course); should this part be: scholarshio = new addScholarship(scholarshipId, course); ?

Comment: no it is still not resolve because it is still inserted as 'dfi',' ' or 'dit',' '@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: The problem with your code is logic. Did you debug the code and checked what values are going for scholarshipId in you BLL and DAL? Are you following the same approach which I suggested in my last post?

Comment: i have tried to debug and really when i checked both, at codebehind, under (dit,checked) method returned "   " while dfi,checked returned me dfi. how do i solve it@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: okay fix it. it should be                 if (DFI.Checked)
            {
                scholarship = new addScholarship(scholarshipId, course);
                scholarshipList.Add(scholarship);
                course = "DFI";         <-------------- this one shld be first.
                DataTable dt = obj.addCourse(scholarshipId, course);
                
            }

Comment: Thanks @skylight. I have corrected my answer accordingly. Good that you could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your connection object in a using statement. Then the compiler will take care what should be done.

```
public DataTable test(string name, string course)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(....))
    {
        string insertsql = "INSERT INTO Table1(schName) OUTPUT INSERTED.addID  values (@schName)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schName", name);
        conn.Open();
        var table1Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        string insertsql1 = "INSERT INTO Table2(ScholarshipID,DiplomaCourse)   values (@id,@course)";

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", table1Id);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error on da.selectCommand =cmd; (the name cmd is does not exist in the current context) do u miss one curly bracket? and do i need to close the conn?