# Get Last Inserted record Id Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am inserting records in database using stored procedures like below

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_insertNewRecord");
```

Now I want to get the Id of last inserted record.

Due to some reason I can't use below function

```
db.TableName.Add(record);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So please don't suggest me to use this.

Comment: Change the stored procedure to output the ID you need, either by returning it or setting it on an output parameter.

Comment: Get your SP to return [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: Due to some(**what?**) reason I can't use below function

Comment: I'd imagine the SP does more than insert into a single table. @LeiYang Or a SQL admin wants all inserts from SPs, etc. This is not uncommon

Answer (score 4):

Create an output variable in your stored procedure like

```
 create procedure [dbo].[Procedurename] @returnVal int output
 as 
 SET @returnVal = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

After inserting the record get the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and set that into an OUTPUT variable.

and get the id in entity framework while calling stored procedure.

Hope this help!