# Display id after insert in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to display the id after inserting the data with the use of stored procedure, my sample stored procedure is like this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertResidence]
@Fname varchar(50),
@Lname varchar(50),
@Mname varchar(50),
@Bdate varchar(50),
@BirthPlace varchar(50),
@CivStat varchar(50),
@Purok varchar(50),
@Religion varchar(50),
@Gender varchar(50),
@CitShip varchar(50)

AS
    Begin tran one;
    Declare @resId INT;
    INSERT INTO [tbl_Residence] (resFname, resLname, resMname, resBdate, resBirthPlace, resGender) VALUES (@Fname,@Lname,@Mname,@Bdate,@BirthPlace,@Gender);
    Select @resId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    NSERT INTO [tbl_Religion] (resId, religion) VALUES (@resId,@Religion);
    INSERT INTO [tbl_Purok] (resId,pur_sit) VALUES (@resId,@Purok);
    INSERT INTO [tbl_Citizenship] (resId,citship) VALUES (@resID,@Purok);
    Select resId from tbl_Residence WHERE resId = @resId;
    commit tran;
RETURN
```

After inserting the data I want to display the id in the label or textboxt.

I use `ExecuteNonQuery()` in the transaction..
This is the code of inserting data in transaction

```
public int insertRes(Informations info)
    {

        //Insert Residence Informations
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertResidence");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Fname;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Lname;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Mname;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Bdate;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.BirthPlace;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CivStat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.CivStat;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purok", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.purok;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Religion;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Gender;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitShip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.CitShip;
        return db.ExeNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

**UI layer :**

[image: UI layer]

**Business layer:**

[image: Business logic layer]

Comment: [get last id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery will only return you the number of rows effected by your command.
Use ExecuteScalar, which will return you resId.

To display:

```
int resId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then in your UI:

```
lblMyLabel.Text = resId.ToString();
```

Comment: but how do i display it in the label with the use of my transaction

Comment: Have updated answer to give a code snippet

Comment: do i need to add this in my parameters? cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Id;

Comment: or replace my ExecuteNonQuery() to ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change your query at all - as long as your command only returns 1 value ExecuteScalar will return that value

Comment: Sir i have updated my post, the first picture is my UI layer and the second is the Business logic layer

Comment: In your Business layer, ExecuteNonQuery needs to be ExecuteScalar. You can then set the text of your label to the value returned from that method.