# How to get the last inserted Id in sql server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi I'm using a stored procedure in sql server to insert a record. The stored procedure in PhP is:

```
 $sp_name = "{CALL sp_PersonInfo_Save(@PersonID=?,@FirstName=?,@LastName=?,@SSN=?,@Email=?,@BirthDate=?,@HireDate=?,@TerminationDate=?,@RetirementDate=?,@DeathDate=?,@Gender=?,@MutialStatus=?,@isActive=?,@Status=?,@Address1=?,@Address2=?,@Phone1=?,@Phone2=?,@City=?,@State=?,@Zip=?,@Country=?,@WhoUpdated=?)} ";
              $params = array(
                    array($var_PersonID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_FirstName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_LastName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_SSN2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_Email, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_BirthDate, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_HireDate, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_TerminationDate, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_RetirementDate, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_DeathDate, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_Gender, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_MaritalStatus, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_IsActive, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_PersonalStatus, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_AddressLine1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_AddressLine2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_Phone1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_Phone2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_City, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_State, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_ZipCode, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_Country, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($var_WhoUpdated, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                  );
     $result = sqlsrv_query($gaSql['link'], $sp_name, $params, array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
```

I need to get this inserted id. I tried using this code:

```
sqlsrv_next_result($result); 
sqlsrv_fetch($result); 
$lastId = sqlsrv_get_field($result, 0);
```

but it didn't work....Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Comment: @rkosegi that link refers to C# answer

Comment: @Pரதீப் can you show me an example?

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez : no, you will find solution not related to C# in linked answer

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez - This is the example, `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` run this query after the insert statement

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez - `SCOPE_IDENTIY` is not a stored procedure, it is a system scalar function which returns the last inserted identity value.

Comment: @Pரதீப் what I meant is that I can't add Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the call of the stored procedure nor modify the stored procedure