# How to get the correct index in a query in multi-user application VB.net and SQL Server

Tags: multi-user

I am creating a multi-user application based on SQL server and VB.NET 
I am adding new row to table and then query to get the new id because its auto generated

```
insert in transactions
```

and then I get the new ID in anther query

```
select Top 1 transaction_ID from Transactions .....
```

and use this id to insert rows in anther table called TransactionDetails

this is safe in single user application. but in multiuser application I might get the wrong  transaction_ID if anther user add anther transaction.

What is the best way to handle that? 
Thank you,

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent to `last_insert_id` that would be returned from your `insert` query? Does this link help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id

Comment: Thank you so much. I found it in your link

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and it works

```
SQL="insert into transactions() values() SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

dim LastID as integer =command.ExecuteScalar(SQL)
```