# Get currently inserted row's id at insertion?

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve inserted row ID in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734589/retrieve-inserted-row-id-in-sql)

Is there any way to get inserted rows id right after the insertion without doing select query? Basically, the idea is like this, I have two tables, one products, and second storage which has 3 columns - id / productId / count . And I need to insert in productId the product Id of the product which I inserted right before this query. So for example -

```
Product with id 1.
```

I insert it into a table for example products, it generates id 1. 
I don't do select, but right after I do another insert which will insert in table storage these data -

`id - 1` / `productId - 1` (took from previous query which generated id 1 with AI) / `count = 0`.

Hope you understood what I ment.

EDIT: I'm using MYSQL database.

Comment: What flavor of database? In MS SQL You could have a stored procedure do the insert that returns @@Identity

Comment: What database are you using? It's entirely possible, but it depends on the database.

Comment: I'm using PHP framework codeigniter and I insert into mysql database.

Comment: Use a stored procedure in conjunction with the answer below "LAST_INSERT_ID()"

Comment: @Grixxly What is the purpose of the stored procedure in this case?

Comment: Personal preference. SQL belongs in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in MySQL, just use the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in your second query.

Comment: Okay, gonna give it a try, hope it will work codeIgniter ;)!

Comment: Edit: Your answer moved me to the correct place, in codeigniter it's very similar - $this->db->insert_id(); will provide last inserted row id. Thank you :) ! I'll accept ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_insert_id();` this is a function of php it will return last inserted id of auto increment type attribute