# How do I insert primary key value from one table to foreign key column in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am new to SQL and programming in general so please bear with me if the answer to this is obvious. I have one table called "tickets" which contains the primary key ticket_id. I also have another table called "contact_info" which stores the contact information of the person who created the ticket. In this table, ticket_id is a foreign key called ticket_number. The user inserts tickets through a GUI and the ticket_number is auto incremented in the database. How do I select the ticket_number and insert it into the row that contains the contact_info of the person who created that ticket?

This is the code right now and it does not do what I expect it to:

```
try{
              //Open a connection
              System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
              this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
              System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

              //Execute a query
              System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
              PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO s_fuse_ticket_table "
                              + " (summary, status, severity, classification, type, internal_notes, description, assignees) "
                              + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                          if(summary.getText().equals("")){
                              throw new SQLException("Summary cannot be blank");
                          }
                          pstmt.setString(1, summary.getText());
                  pstmt.setString(2, status.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
                  pstmt.setString(3, severity.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
                          if(classification.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Make a Selection")){
                              throw new SQLException("Please select a classification");
                          }
                          pstmt.setString(4, classification.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
                          if(type.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Make a Selection")){
                              throw new SQLException("Please select a type");
                          }
                          pstmt.setString(5, type.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
                          pstmt.setString(6, internalNotes.getText());
                          pstmt.setString(7, description.getText());
                          pstmt.setString(8, assignee.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
                  pstmt.executeUpdate();

                          //Execute a query
                        System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
                        PreparedStatement pstmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO s_fuse_contact_info_table "
                              + " (ticket_number, email, last_name, first_name) "
                              + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

                          pstmt2.setString(1, ("SELECT ticket_id FROM s_fuse_ticket_table"));
                          /*if(!email.getText().contains("@") && !email.getText().contains(".")){

                          }*/
                          pstmt2.setString(2, email.getText());
                          pstmt2.setString(3, lname.getText());
                          pstmt2.setString(4, fname.getText());
                  pstmt2.executeUpdate();
           }catch(SQLException se){
              //Handle errors for JDBC
              se.printStackTrace();
           }catch(Exception e){
              //Handle errors for Class.forName
              e.printStackTrace();
           }finally{
              //finally block used to close resources
              try{
                 if(stmt!=null)
                 {
                    connection.close();
                 }
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }// do nothing
              try{
                 if(connection!=null)
                 {
                    connection.close();
                 }
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }//end finally try
           }//end try
           System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different DBMS' have different ways to do this - refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734589/retrieve-inserted-row-id-in-sql) for a pretty comprehensive list.

Another way is to use transactions.  With an MVCC DBMS in a suitable isolation level (repeatable read or serializable), when you start a new connection you will have your own view of the db, so you can `INSERT INTO` the main table, then `SELECT` the latest row that matches your insert and be confident that it belongs to you.  It's a good idea to bundle inserts like this together anyway, as it prevents any inconsistent data getting into the system - just make sure you commit afterward!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so helpful and easy to understand

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a transaction that looks like what you are describing? (with the bundled inserts)

Comment: A transaction typically begins with

Comment: A transaction typically begins with:
`BEGIN WORK;`
You can then do multiple statements:
`INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,2,3,4);
`INSERT INTO tablea VALUES ('a','b');

And then either 'COMMIT' to apply both changes at once, or `ROLLBACK` to undo them both and restore the database.

Comment: Something like: `INSERT INTO ptable (id, name) VALUES (0, "Chips Rafferty");
INSERT into ftable(ptable_id, tag) SELECT max(id), "Actor" FROM ptable WHERE name = "Chips Rafferty");
COMMIT;`

Comment: Thank you so so much. :)